# Custom math mode font

Tags: math-mode, fonts, fontspec, math-fonts

I created a custom font `Computer Modern Roman Blackboard Bold`, similar to the `Computer Modern Roman - italic` as the following image:

[image]

As you can imagine, I want to implement this font in `math-mode` such as `\cmrbb{hello}` or maybe substitute `\mathsf` alphabet for mine, then rename a new command `\cmrbb`.

#### Specifications

- I'm using `fontspec`
- I'm using `LuaLaTeX`
- I have some packages like `amsmath, amssymb, mathtools` (I don't know if it can cause trouble)
- I want to use the new font as a simple command like `\cmrbb{text}` inside math-mode
- I'm working currently on Overleaf and have loaded `cmrbb.ttf`

I have no idea how I can do it, I tried using `mathspec` but the document doesn't even compile (I think it only works in `XeLaTeX`).

And just in case there is no incompatibility, I don't use any command for font encoding, and I have already loaded some fonts. I don't know much about fontspec, any additional information to make it easier to implement the solution would be really helpful.

Comment: If anyone is looking for CM outline style upright blackboard letters, then the cmathbb package provides it. Unfortunately, it works only on Windows as of now due to a bug. https://ctan.org/pkg/cmathbb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear if your font is OT1 encoded like the original cmr or TU Unicode encoded, but basically

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\cmrbb}{OT1}{cmrbb}{m}{n}
```

or

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\cmrbb}{TU}{cmrbb}{m}{n}
```

together with a suitable fd file if using OT1 and declare the font using `\newfontfamily\cmrbbfam[NFSSFamily=cmrbb]` if using TU encoded fonts.

An example (produced with xelatex) using some opentype font found on this system, the declarations would be the same for any font.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\cmrbbfam{Goudy Stout}[NFSSFamily=cmrbb]
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\cmrbb}{TU}{cmrbb}{m}{n}

\begin{document}


\[
  a=\cmrbb{N}+\cmrbb{xyz} + y
  \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\cmrbb}{OT1}{cmrbb}{m}{n}` with OT1 or TU uses the computer modern roman font (the default in text-mode) and with the `\newfontfamily` it returns the error `Package fontspec Error: The font "N" cannot be found.` I added in the specifications that I'm using Overleaf and I've loaded cmrbb.ttf in between the documents, just in case it has to do with it.

Comment: @Agente156 I added an example for xelatex